# Android - Data storage?

Tags: iphone, android, core-data, data-storage

I am converting an iphone app to android?

1- Is there anything similar to the "iphones core data" on android sdk?

2- If not, does android support using sqlite databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you can see the documentation of the sqlite database in android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Here is a good descirption of various possibilities on how to store data in android:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 2):

For other readers that are looking for a Core Data replacement in Android, I suggest an ORM tool like [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/). It allows you work with Java objects and uses SQLite as its storage back end.